# Facebook Feed Plugin issue

Tags: facebook, plugins

I have used the Social Plugin in the past to place an HTML newsfeed on a website. I'm trying to do the same thing, but I'm not getting the feed to display. In fact, if I visit https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/activity the demo is not displaying. Could this be something with my browser, or a bug in the plugin? Any guidance is much appreciated!!

I have this immediately after the body tag, and I have the html pasted in it's proper place.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
// init the FB JS SDK
FB.init({
  appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
  status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
  xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the        page
  });

  // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(){
     // If we've already installed the SDK, we're done
     if (document.getElementById('facebook-jssdk')) {return;}

     // Get the first script element, which we'll use to find the parent node
     var firstScriptElement = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

     // Create a new script element and set its id
     var facebookJS = document.createElement('script'); 
     facebookJS.id = 'facebook-jssdk';

     // Set the new script's source to the source of the Facebook JS SDK
     facebookJS.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';

     // Insert the Facebook JS SDK into the DOM
     firstScriptElement.parentNode.insertBefore(facebookJS, firstScriptElement);
   }());
</script>

<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Comment: appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', you have to write your app id

Comment: wow I should have caught that. Sorry! Thanks so much @Chai-YuPai. If I have to do this for a client, I will need them to get their app id, correct? It is not a public thing?